# fixed distance joint not working right

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, physics

I want two pieces of my ship to be attached at a constant distance point so I tried to use the corresponding joint.  The behaviour starts out looking like the correct movement, but after a few seconds the two boxes just drift apart aimlessly.

I apply a force on one box to get movement going and make sure they don't collide.  I searched and found a similar problem a guy was having but it looked like a patch was created so I don't know if it was fixed.

```
import Foundation

class Battle: CCNode, CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate {

var scenePhysics = CCPhysicsNode()

override init() {
    super.init()

    scenePhysics.collisionDelegate = self
    self.addChild(scenePhysics)
    buildShip()
}

func buildShip(){

    var booster = CCSprite(imageNamed: "Booster.png")
    booster.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 150)
    booster.scale = 4
    var boosterPhysics = CCPhysicsBody(rect: booster.textureRect, cornerRadius: 0)
    boosterPhysics.collisionCategories = ["cat1"]
    boosterPhysics.collisionMask = ["cat2"]
    boosterPhysics.collisionType = "nodeA"
    boosterPhysics.applyForce(CGPoint(x: 2000, y: 1))
    booster.physicsBody = boosterPhysics
    scenePhysics.addChild(booster)


    var booster2 = CCSprite(imageNamed: "Booster.png")
    booster2.position = CGPoint(x: booster.position.x + 90, y: booster.position.y)
    booster2.scale = 4
    var boosterPhysics2 = CCPhysicsBody(rect: booster2.textureRect, cornerRadius: 0)
    boosterPhysics2.collisionCategories = ["cat2"]
    boosterPhysics2.collisionMask = []
    boosterPhysics2.collisionType = "nodeB"
    booster2.physicsBody = boosterPhysics2
    scenePhysics.addChild(booster2)


    CCPhysicsJoint(distanceJointWithBodyA: boosterPhysics, bodyB: boosterPhysics2, anchorA: CGPointZero, anchorB: CGPointZero)

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

K so I changed the anchor point to be the content size of boosterphysics and it works with a pin joint so I'm happy now.